# How is a static constant useful in an anonymous class?

Tags: java, static, anonymous-types

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#:%7E:text=Anonymous%20classes%20also%20have%20the,that%20they%20are%20constant%20variables.) for the anonymous classes states:

> Anonymous classes also have the same restrictions as local classes with respect to their members:
>
> - You cannot declare static initializers or member interfaces in an anonymous class.
> - An anonymous class can have static members provided that they are constant variables.

I don't understand how would a **static** constant in an anonymous class be useful in practice. Static methods can't be overridden and we can't access the anonymous class's members from outside, therefore we don't need to use static constants.

Am I missing something or is it something that's not practical in any way, but it's permitted anyways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing:

1. Naming constants provide clarity to the programmers that needs to maintain the code.
2. Naming a constant allows it to be used in multiple places in the anonymous class code, making it easier to change later without missing a spot.

This is really no different than using `private` constants in any other class.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I'm trying to understand why it would be "static".

Comment: @somMelon Java defines a **constant field** as being a `static final` field. --- Although technically, according to [JLS 4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4), constant *variables* don't need to be `static`; but since the value of a *field* will always be the same regardless of the instance, having non-static constants makes no sense, so the rest of the JLS treats **constant field** as being a `static final` field.

Comment: But in the context of an anonymous class, is there a point in making it static?

Comment: @somMelon There is always a point in making a **constant** static, i.e. not wasting instance specific memory with values that are not specific to the instance.

Comment: Good catch, I remembered that differently. So your answer stands, and rightfully so.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you! If you change your answer to this (or make a new one), I'll accept it.

Comment: @somMelon Answer will not be changed unless the question is changed. Question currently is *"how would a static constant in an anonymous class be useful?"*, and that is exactly what this answer addresses. If your question is not that, edit and clarify the question, then I might change the answer to fit the new (real?) question you have.

Comment: I was specifically asking about static though. In your answer, you are talking about usefulness of constants in general. At least I understand it that way.

Comment: What I had in mind when I was asking this question was just how would I access the static member like I would in a normal class (Class.MEMBER). And since we can't access members of an anonymous class like that, it didn't make sense why would I use the static keyword. I didn't think about memory there and when you made that comment, it clicked for me.

Comment: @Andreas sorry, forgot to notify you.

Comment: @somMelon Since *constant fields* are always `static final` in Java, simply bolding the word "static" doesn't change the meaning of the question. --- If you wanted to know *"why it would be "static""* *(from first comment)*, you should have asked that explicitly in the question. --- If you wanted to know *"how would I access the static member"*, then I'm indirectly answering that with *"in the anonymous class code"* already. You seem to only think of how constants are access by other classes, ignoring that fields are primarily for internal use, constants included.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I was tunnel-visioned on accessing it from other class. Didn't really think about static fields as a means to save memory. Thanks for your time.